Asus Laptop ACPI Errors
I'm using an Asus UX3404VA laptop. I wanted to set the charge_control_end_threshold as described here. I can set the value but it has no effect. The kernel version I use is 6.9.3-76060903-generic and the OS is PopOS 22.04.
I've tested this on my older Asus laptop and it works as expected.
I see the following log lines in the dmesg | grep -i acpi output.
Does it suggest that I should upgrade the BIOS or upgrade the kernel?
[    1.699741] ACPI: button: Lid Switch [LID0]
[    1.699788] ACPI: button: Power Button [PWRB]
[    1.699951] ACPI: button: Power Button [PWRF]
[    1.700044] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PC00.LPCB.HEC.CFSP], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230628/psargs-330)
[    1.700057] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.H_EC.TFN1._FST due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20230628/psparse-529)
[    1.700062] acpi INTC10A2:00: Get fan state failed
[    1.704024] ACPI: thermal: Thermal Zone [TZ00] (28 C)
[    1.705224] ACPI: battery: Slot [BAT0] (battery present)
[    1.706701] hpet_acpi_add: no address or irqs in _CRS
[    1.732233] ACPI: bus type drm_connector registered
[    6.452204] ACPI: bus type thunderbolt registered
[    8.207683] ACPI: video: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[    9.463963] system76_acpi: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[    9.463967] system76_acpi: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   10.558101] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PC00.XHCI.RHUB.HS10._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Integer], ACPI requires [Package] (20230628/nsarguments-61)
[   10.637159] ACPI: battery: new extension: ASUS Battery Extension
[   11.887089] ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: error -ETIMEDOUT: PPM init failed
[ 1227.260749] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [^^^^NPCF.DBAC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230628/psargs-330)
[ 1227.260831] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.H_EC._Q80 due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20230628/psparse-529)
[ 1473.002814] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [^^^^NPCF.DBAC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20230628/psargs-330)
[ 1473.002870] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.H_EC._Q80 due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20230628/psparse-529)


The fact that you can't set a charge endpoint might have nothing to do with the ACPI errors you see, or it might be. I don't fully understand ACPI naming,  but I'm not sure things like charge controller interactions are typically done through it.
The ACPI errors themselves:
This suggests that the ACPI tables in your laptop are invalid. Maybe a firmware update fixes that – if not, there's really nothing software can do: the table with the instructions on how to do such things simply contain invalid data that can't be correctly "guessed". Maybe an Asus employee sits down and upstreams a kernel quirk for your specific device, but I wouldn't hold my breath.
Independent remark: you're trying to load "system76_acpi", wnich is a driver for system76 devices, which this laptop is none of. Usually, kernel modules are loaded on-demand when matching hardware is found, but this seems to be forced. I don't know whether that is the default on PopOS (even on non-System76 hardware), but you should probably disable that.

Thanks, dear Marcus. You're right. I agree I should disable the system76_acpi.
I've copy-pasted all the logs as it is the only clue I have about the issue.

yeah, as said, so assume the thing you want to do is simply not supported by the hardware.
